# Need help grayscaling with 'Imager' package: Error in grayscale(im) : Image should have three colour channels

Tags: r, imagemagick

I saved the image from [this link](https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/512/56/2576481/PMC2576481_mv-v14-1965-f2.png) locally and loaded it in. I need to be able to convert this is grayscale, get a histogram of the luminescence, and manipulate it with grabRect.

This is my initial attempt

```
library(tidyverse)
library(imager)

im <- load.image("my/directory/retina_samples.png")

plot(im) #retina!
grayscale(im)
```

> Error in grayscale(im) : Image should have three colour channels

I can circumvent this issue and yield the luminance plot I want by going another route:

```
library(magick)
im2 <- cimg2im(im, W = NULL)
plot(im2$`c = 1`)
im2.1 <-im2$`c = 1`
im2.1 %>% hist(main="Luminance values in  Retina Angiography", breaks = 30)
```

I'm halfway there! But now I get a different error when I try to work with grabRect

```
grabRect(im2.1)
```

> Error in if (depth(im) > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thoughts?